# how to change storage path in Laravel5.1 on different environment?

Tags: php, laravel

I set a config in .env file on prod environment.

```
STORAGE_PATH=/dev/shm/runtime
```

and write the following codes in bootstrap/app.php.

```
if (env('STORAGE_PATH')) {
    $app->useStoragePath(env('STORAGE_PATH'));
}
```

it doesn't work because `env('STORAGE_PATH')` returns empty string. It seems that .env file has not been loaded.

someone suggests to do this in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function register()
{
    if (env('STORAGE_PATH')) {
        $this->app->useStoragePath(env('STORAGE_PATH'));
        /* or 
         $this->app->bind('path.storage', function () {
                return env('STORAGE_PATH');
        });
        */
    }
}
```

tried, didn't work.

I believe there must be an elegant way to do this job.

Comment: Does `useStoragePath()` work if you put string in it? What does `dd(env('STORAGE_PATH'));` return if you put it in register method?

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin it work with stirng in bootstrap/app.php, the problem is .env file has not been loaded, then where should i write the config value?

Comment: Did you try string in `register()` method? What does `dd()` return? Without this information noone will be able to help you.

Comment: in register() method, `dd(env('STORAGE_PATH'))` return expected value.  it just change the value of Application::$storagePath,  but did not effect with the true path. Like i said to @Kelvin Kyaw.

Answer (score 0):

Remove code from `bootstrap/app.php`.

Checkout my attachment image. It's worked with 5.1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just print out `dd` in view file.

```
 <div class="title">Laravel 5 {{dd($app->storagePath())}}</div>
```

Comment: thanks to check it. this way do change the value of Application::$storagePath,  but it didn't change the true path.  check the fold storage/famework/views/, the new-created view cache file will still in it.